# How do I handle whether or not to create a database in Sequel?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sequel

I am using Sequel with SQLite and want like to create the database from Ruby code if the SQLite database file does not exist yet. I could use the File class to look for the file but I am wondering if there is something in Sequel to handle this for me?

At first I was creating all the tables each run of the program using  `create_table?` that only creates a table if it does not already  exist. This worked fine until I needed a join table. There is no `create_join_table?` that only creates a join table if it does not exist.

Any suggestions for handling database creation in the application?

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of SQLite access in Sequel is to create the database if it does not exist.

You can do:

```
join_table_opts = {...}
DB.create_join_table(join_table_opts) unless DB.table_exists?(DB.send(:join_table_name, join_table_opts))
```

but it may be easier t to use `create_table?` and create the join table manually.  `create_join_table` doesn't really save you all that much code (a couple lines at most).